# Handling scrollbar width in flex layout

Tags: javascript, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I'm trying to build a tabular list which is scrollable with a fixed header row.  It is all working well, except that the headers go out of line with the columns when the scrollbar is shown.  A simplified example of the markup is:

```
<div layout="column">
  <div>
    <div layout="row">
      <div flex="25">
        <span>Col 1</span>
      </div>
      <div flex="25">
        <span>Col 2</span>
      </div>
      <div flex="50">
        <span>Col 3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <md-virtual-repeat-container flex layout-fill>
    <div md-virtual-repeat="row in rows" md-on-demand flex>
      <div layout="row">
        <div flex="25">
          <span ng-bind="row.col1"></span>
        </div>
        <div flex="25">
          <span ng-bind="row.col2"></span>
        </div>
        <div flex="50">
          <span ng-bind="row.col3"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </md-virtual-repeat-container>
</div>
```

The problem is that when the rows overflow, a scrollbar is shown and the flex calculation on the rows accounts for it while the header (with no scrollbar) doesn't which causes the misalignment.  The best solution I can think of right now is to always show the scrollbar on the rows (it will usually overflow) and add some JavaScript to calculate the scrollbar width for the current browser and add a matching right-margin to the header but I'd rather not do that if there is a better way?

Comment: If you provide a working code snippet, we will be able to provide a proper answer.